# Div switch effect JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 divs that hide and unhide with JavaScript by clicking the menu on the top of the page. I have got this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(d) {
        var onediv = document.getElementById(d);
        var divs= ['content1', 'content2', 'content3', 'content4'];
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            if (onediv != document.getElementById(divs[i])) {
                document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        onediv.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to add the an effect that when you show a new div it comes rolling in from the top, like this "http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/48152.html". Can you do this with JavaScript or do I need jQuery? If I need to make use of jQuery which one must i use?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. Everything jQuery does is possible with native JavaScript.

Comment: With jquery plugins you can achieve these effects http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/animation/

Comment: CSS animation has many effects which will spare you a lot of javascript but as of today is limited to the newer browser versions

Comment: Have a look at `slideToggle()`
https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jQuery's `$show()`, `$hide()` and `$toggle()` methods.

Adding a parameter of milliseconds will cause a delay.

```
$toggle(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for effects you will nedd jQuery. Just replace

```
 document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'none';

 onediv.style.display = 'block';
```

with

```
 document.getElementById(divs[i]).slideUp();

 onediv.slideDown();
```

Call your ( showHide(d) ) function on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use JQuery slide down method for this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$(document.getElementById(d)).slideDown();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, How do I make the links for my menu with this method because I cannot make that work.

Comment: @user3276074 Could you create a jsfiddle so that i could check it